# Operating large numbers of VM's

Tags: virtual, virtualization, hypervisor

I have a machine and I need to run some tests on it. These tests involve firing up a large number of identical VM's (up to ~1000) at the same time, and commanding them all to do the same thing at the same time.

Does anyone know the best hypervisor with which to do this? I've been searching a while and nobody seems to be interested in doing this. All I can find is about running multiple VM's on a single host, which isn't really helpful.

Any thoughts are appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a big lot of RAM on your (physical) computer. You probably need hundreds of gigabytes of RAM.

Comment: Are you load testing? would you care to expand on the 'same time' requirement? And why on identical machines - lots of?

Comment: We're doing research into how the use of many VM's on a single host affects the entropy produced by RNG's. As for the eventual number, we're going to get as many on the machine as possible, we were simply hoping for maybe 1000 as our eventual end, but it was totally an arbitrary number.  As for the machine, I haven't got the specs at the moment, but our tests are going to start with 2 and 4 VM's at once, so the idea is still necessary. We just need the ability to scale up.

Thanks for the quick replies though! Any ideas?

Comment: @RyanVincent, we need to use identical machines to minimize variables in the results. And we need to run the, at the same time because nobody wants to sign into a bunch of individual VM's to start a job on each one. And then they would be returning different results on the first one as the load on the host is less until the others get going.

Basically, we need to minimize variables in the test machine and make large numbers of machines possible.

Comment: Sounds interesting. so what you propose is one real machine can generate 'one unit of entropy per unit time' (randomness) but ten virtual machines running on that one machine can generate more than 'one unit of entropy per unit time'?

Comment: @RyanVincent, actually, at the moment, we don't know what to expect. But we understand that not much research has been done as far as looking at the interaction between massively virtualized environments and entropy. If there is a lowering of entropy, that would be a problem, if there's a rise in entropy, that would be great! But we don't know what to expect. But that's what research is all about! :)

Speaking of which, I'm beginning to think that using KVM vm's and libvirt would allow me to control many VM's from scripts.  So far that's my best lead. Any thoughts there anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, everyone, this was solved in a very easy way!  We simply created some Python server and client scripts and set them to run on boot.  That way we could simply have each VM boot up and wait for a signal on the virtual network.  On that signal, they start their work.  This gets them very close to exactly the same timing.  So, the easiest solution, simply use a virtual network to set them all going!

Thanks all!